# How to design a Wi-Fi network for maximum range?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, remote-access

For a project I need a Wi-Fi network with a decent range, let's say 300 metres or more and with still a decent data rate (3-4 Mbps), **with one user**.
Is that even possible? I could place the AP very high above most of the obstacles around my house would that help?

Option 1:
[image]

Option 2:
[image]

Comment: Is this for a fixed point-to-point link (where both ends are stationary)? If not, is 300m the intended radius or the intended diameter? How many clients need to get the 3-4Mbps of throughput simultaneously?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is encouraging answers that are making hardware recommendations .  Questions seeking hardware recommendations are not within scope.

Comment: @Spiff Ok, I updated the question and added 2 pics for explanation as well, and thanks  for editing!

Comment: While I think this question will encourage answers which make hardware recommendations, instead of actually answering the question, I still request you crop the images in the event the question can be salvaged..  All you should have to do is change the link to the image and submit the edit.

Comment: There are wireless radios and antennae capable of driving this distance, but the other side of the equation will be a problem: The device you're connecting to the wireless network will need to also be capable of sending a strong-enough signal in return.

Comment: @music2myear Ouch, I ve not thought about that, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the accepted answer is correct, it is, I feel, only very partial.

A key trick to understanding performance is that its about Signal to noise ratio and bandwidth - maximize this and you maximize performance.

Additional considerations for maximizing performance include:

1. The more directional the aerials the further the signal can travel / the more speed you can get).   Relatedly, the higher the gain of an antenna the smaller its range (in higher gain omni aerials this is done by reducing the height profile of the aerials)
2. Clearance from obstacles.  In addition to line of site, you ideally want fresnel clearance - which is an additional amount of clearance depending on the wavelength and distance (think of it like a rugby ball shaped zone of free space between the antenna, with the height of the clearance being determined by the frequency and distance between points).
3. Amplifiers can sometimes help but increase both the signal and noise.   Often it is better to get more sensitive antennas.
4. You can improve signal depending on your orientation/polarization of aerial in 3 ways - vertical, horizontal and circular polarization)
5. Frequencies - the lower the frequency the further a signal can travel reliably, but the slower it will work.   Axiomatically the higher the frequency range you use, the more available spectrum and the faster you can transmit, and, if limited to the "free" bands, less congested they are likely to be.    Similarly, you can bond multiple frequencies to get more throughput - but this can cause a tragedy of the commons.

500 meters is almost trivial to get provided there is not to much competition for spectrum (which can be a major issue in built up areas, and can prevent reliable service).  Its entirely practical to do a point-to-point shot of 20kms.     (Ubiquity does some really cool external gear that is very affordable).

Depending on your location, look closely at the regulations - different countries have different bands, however a lot of equipment does not make use of some bands which may be legal because they want to sell the same thing everywhere - sometimes finding a band which is legal in your country but not others - and with supported software - can help.

Don't underestimate the possibility of using 5 gig gear - it has a much smaller range and much more frequencies and speed, so less congestion and noise for you to pick up.  You can easily do upwards of 2 kms with 5 gig gear and high speed.

Using newer standards you can go faster on the same frequency and power.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But what kind of antenna do I need then when I would have to cover 90-180 degree? Something like this: [this](https://www.amazon.com/Antenna-World-P2418120-Sector/dp/B00NQGUC5S/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1518859729&sr=8-4&keywords=sector+panel+antenna) or [this](https://www.amazon.de/UbiQuiti-NanoBeam-antenna-2-4GHz-AirMax/dp/B00JIU0AKS/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1518859981&sr=8-7&keywords=Ubiquiti+Airmax) or [this](https://www.amazon.de/Ubiquiti-antenna-AirMax-13dBi-rocket-Wei%C3%9F/dp/B00HXT89H2/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1518859981&sr=8-6&keywords=Ubiquiti+Airmax) ?

Comment: Or, does [this](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Outdoor-WLAN-WiFi-Antenne-Langstreckenbereich-Booster-Kabellos-bis-1-2-5-Meile/322545992966?hash=item4b193d4506:g:b64AAOSw~f5Z3dAk) rly work, or is it scam?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't adequately understand its claims it makes as I don't speak German, but with respect of the last link its not suitable for what you want.(You don't want a repeater)  If it's claiming a range of 3000 meters - its a scam. Ive also not seen a USB powered long range radio. It's also very cheap, so unlikely to have low noise componentry.

Comment: With respect of the antennas, I'm not comfortable in recommending stuff for point to multipoint (it's a lot harder to get right because of noise). The Ubiquity device is probably adequate for customers, and the first link coupled with a suitable radio might work for the Central point - but I don't have enough specs on it. You might want to Google panel antenna to find other options. (Your original post talked about 1 user - not multiple users, While I imagine that 300 meters on an Omni to point-to-point is doable, it's not something I would offer as a reliable service.)

Answer (score 0):

You would need at least a wireless N technology router placed high and in the center of the areas to cover. The walls construction may or may not make a difference in signal strength.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the AP600EX from Amped Wireless can do the job for you.  It has High Power 600mW Wi-Fi Amplifier and High Gain Directional Antenna to provide maximum range.  It's USD$150 - Good Luck

https://www.ampedwireless.com/ap600ex.html

Comment: Thank you but I can t buy it here in germany...

Answer (score 0):

You have options,

100m is usually the defacto for consumer wireless.
But there are commercially available routers that have built in amplifiers. Additionally newer devices utilize LNA low noise amplifiers & ULNA Ultra low noise amplifiers.

Note: depending on your country region you may have laws preventing you from transmitting at higher signal power. Check your local radio regulator rules for 2.4ghz and 5ghz bands 
(This is so everyone can use their devices not just you)

1. Buy a consumer solution as Pythonian suggested. The manufacturer "buffalo" also has a high power series of routers that has two-way pre-amps connected to the individual TX/RX chains in the device. (cons, not out-door, obsticles/walls, and you would most likley need one device at each end of the link)
2. You can use multiple AP's with directional antennas, but they need to have their settings match. Same SSID, same security settings, but on different channels. I.e 1,6,&11 (pro's good overall radius coverage when using honeycombing / Cons, more devices needed, more power consumed, complex to the average user to get working.)
3. Go with a professional solution. There are many out-door options available, where you would be mounting it on the roof or on the side of a building. An example would be something like the "Engenious EOC-5610" which has a range of 1km to 30km in absolute ideal environmental conditions.  Pro's ,superb radio sensitivity , built-in directional antennas, built-in LNA-ULNA for superior transmission distance. / Cons, need someone to install it, usually higher in price, may not be legal in some locations. Most likley would need one on each end for anything past 1000ft in this kind of environment.

Additionally you should perform a site survey, i use "wiggle WiFi" for android in environments like this, its also available in the apple store under "wiggle where". You would then walk around your block scanning with it as it marks SSID with the highest signal strength to GPS location. It then allows you to export a kml file for a google maps overlay. Allowing you to see what channels your neighbors are using geographically vs the radio path you are trying to connect over. (the last time i used it i technically had to walk around twice, one for 2.4 and one for 5ghz not sure if they updated it)

Make sure you check your RF rules in your area with the local regulatory authority. You can get in pretty serious trouble and possibly get your communications gear confiscated if you disregard the warning.